# Show image, wait 10 second and load page content

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to stop html loading after an specific img tag, wait 10 seconds.. and continue...

i mean, the lines at below of `<img id='waitme' src='logo.png'>`, must be read/load 10 seconds after the selected img tag(#waitme).

i tried with JQUERY wait(), delay() functions; but couldnt solve.

i will add this img tag at after  tag, and all content of the site must be load 10 seconds after this image shown.

show #waitme, wait 10 second, load page content..

Could someone help me?

Comment: why stop the page from loading? keep the page loading while displaying the image, and hide the image after 10 seconds or whatever ... anyway, you can't stop the page loading, so re-think what you want to do instead

Comment: its a logo animation; and i just need to show 10 second logo animation before content.. (as like preloader.gif, which plays 10 seconds)

Comment: so what? you can't stop the page from loading part way

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
...
<style>
     .disabled{
           display: none;}
</style>
<body>
 <img src="your_image.jpg" id="ur_img">
 <div id="wrap" class="disabled">
      Here is your content
 </div>
 <script>
     setTimeout(function(){
          $("#wrap").removeClass("disabled");
          $("#ur_img").addClass("disabled");
         }, 10000)

 </script>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve what you want,

1. Display this image in `document's ready handler` and hide the page's content.
2. Start a `timeOut` function in `windows load` handler with 10k
   milliseconds.
3. In the call back of timeout, hide the image and display the page
   content.